# Formatting price in INR method

Tags: php, currency, number-formatting, price

I have a piece of code, which formats a number to INR Price (₹1.00/- , ₹10,00,000.00/- , etc.):

```
function price_format($num,$type = 1){
    $num_full = number_format($num,2);
    if (strpos($num, '.') !== false) {
    $num = substr($num_full, 0, strpos($num_full, "."));
    }
    
    if($type == 1){ // '₹10,00,000.00/-'
        $explrestunits = "" ;
    if(strlen($num)>3) {
        $lastthree = substr($num, strlen($num)-3, strlen($num));
        $restunits = substr($num, 0, strlen($num)-3); // extracts the last three digits
        $restunits = (strlen($restunits)%2 == 1)?"0".$restunits:$restunits; // explodes the remaining digits in 2's formats, adds a zero in the beginning to maintain the 2's grouping.
        $expunit = str_split($restunits, 2);
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($expunit); $i++) {
            // creates each of the 2's group and adds a comma to the end
            if($i==0) {
                $explrestunits .= (int)$expunit[$i].","; // if is first value , convert into integer
            } else {
                $explrestunits .= $expunit[$i].",";
            }
        }
        $thecash = "₹".$explrestunits.$lastthree.substr($num_full, -3, strpos($num_full, "."))."/-";
    } else {
        $thecash = "₹".$num.substr($num_full, -3, strpos($num_full, "."))."/-";
    }
    return $thecash; // writes the final format where $currency is the currency symbol.
    }
}
```

For the below test, it is not giving as expected result.

```
echo price_format(1)."<br />";
echo price_format(10)."<br />";
echo price_format(84289.35);
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/eNYDl)

Also, the code is open and I am happy if someone wants to have this code more clear and short

Comment: Look at `number_format` function.

Comment: @AlivetoDie The code shared, has issue for *₹ 8,42,89,.35* (, near decimal). Also, I want ₹1.00/- if we send only 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no use of `strpos` while setting the value to `$thecash`. [strpos doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Use `number_format()`  as: `number_format((float)$num,2,'.','');`

[Working Code](https://3v4l.org/cEQUI):-

```
function price_format($num,$type = 1){
    $num_full = number_format((float)$num,2,'.','');
    if (strpos($num, '.') !== false) {
    $num = substr($num_full, 0, strpos($num_full, "."));
    }
    
    if($type == 1){ // '₹10,00,000.00/-'
        $explrestunits = "" ;
    if(strlen($num)>3) {
        $lastthree = substr($num, strlen($num)-3, strlen($num));
        $restunits = substr($num, 0, strlen($num)-3); // extracts the last three digits
        $restunits = (strlen($restunits)%2 == 1)?"0".$restunits:$restunits; // explodes the remaining digits in 2's formats, adds a zero in the beginning to maintain the 2's grouping.
        $expunit = str_split($restunits, 2);
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($expunit); $i++) {
            // creates each of the 2's group and adds a comma to the end
            if($i==0) {
                $explrestunits .= (int)$expunit[$i].","; // if is first value , convert into integer
            } else {
                $explrestunits .= $expunit[$i].",";
            }
        }
        $thecash = "₹".$explrestunits.$lastthree.substr($num_full, -3)."/-";
    } else {
        $thecash = "₹".$num.substr($num_full, -3)."/-";
    }
    return $thecash; // writes the final format where $currency is the currency symbol.
    }
}

echo price_format(1).PHP_EOL;
echo price_format(10).PHP_EOL;
echo price_format(84289.35);
```

Comment: for decimal values more than 3 it will truncate them to 2 digit :  https://3v4l.org/6o0ms . Still a more accurate solution.+1